# An example of WorkManager and AlarmManager working together?

Tags: android, android-studio, alarmmanager

I'm trying to piece together how to send notifications for a calendar using AlarmManager and WorkManager. I've been confused on how to exactly implement these two things together. Are there any examples online of this?

Comment: `WorkManager` uses `AlarmManager` under the hood, so you don't have to use those two independently. Read more about here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/

Comment: Muddz, I fixed this problem, but just so you know there is a use case for using AlarmManager and WorkManager separately. WorkManager has a minimum of 15 minutes on periodic work requests, whereas AlarmManager is 60 seconds. That's why I was using AlarmManager to wake up the worker

Comment: Dylan are you sure a minimum of 15 minutes for WorkManager? that seems odd

Comment: There have been some updates since this question was asked, so it's possible it's changed since then.